# Programatically changing the state of a RadDataForm Switch editor

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm creating a new angular + nativescript application that is dependent on the RadDataForm plugin for the creation of a form. I have created a source object that will initialise the editors and is working correctly. Among the editors, i have a switch which i want to use to perform programatic actions when its state changes. How do i get to access the state of the switch in my code? i am using a json file to customise the editors.

i have tried adding the switch "checkedChange" event and its handler as explained in the nativescript ui widgets but it does not work.

These are the editors from my "Issue" Object

```
  public isResolved?: boolean;
  public reasonForNotResolving?: string;
```

this is how im registering my source object in the RadDataForm :

first i initialise my Object in the ngOnInit() method like :

```
  this.createIssue = new Issue(
      false,
      'Development Env Was Not Set',
    );
```

then use the "createIssue" property as my source object like:

```
      <RadDataForm
        #issuesLogForm
        tkExampleTitle
        tkToggleNavButton
        [source]="createIssue"
        [metadata]="issueLogMeta"
      >
      </RadDataForm>
```

my metadata provided by a json file looks like below:

```
{
    "isReadOnly": false,
    "commitMode": "Manual",
    "validationMode": "Manual",
    "propertyAnnotations":
    [
{
            "name": "isResolved",
            "displayName": "issue is Resolved :",
            "index": 5,
            "editor": "Switch"
        },
        {
            "name": "reasonForNotResolving",
            "displayName": "Reason For Not Resolving :",
            "index": 6,
            "editor": "MultilineText"
        }, 
]
}
```

i'm expecting to get the state of my switch editor and alter it programatically in my code. such that when the switch editor for "issue is Resolved" is checked, the editor for "reasonForNotResolving" should be disabled and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [propertyCommitted](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/raddataform#propertycommittedevent) event to monitor any changes on the data form. You may filter the particular property by comparing the `propertyName` attribute in the event object.

```
onPropertyCommitted(args) {
    if (args.propertyName === "isResolved") {
        // createIssue.isResolved should have the latest value here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I also noted that the propertyCommitted event is highly affected by the commitMode chosen.